# Camera2: setting optical stabilization does nothing (OIS)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I have Samsung S10 which has video stabilization feature.
Using system default Camera app I can see the difference when it's enabled and not: first if it's enabled than there will be some zoomed preview, second it is noticeable during device movements.

[image]

I tried to enable stabilization in my own app using Camera2 API, also FullHD and rear camera (the same as with default system app).

I tested that `characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AVAILABLE_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODES)` returns only `CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF` so this is not supported.

But `characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION)`
has `CameraMetadata.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON`

So I as I understand this is exactly the option to enable video stabilization (optical), should be the same as in default system app.

But when I do the next for camera capture session configuration it doesn't change anything, no zoomed preview (as it was with default system camera app) and no changes during movement, so the video is the same in my app as it would have been in default camera app with disabled video stabilization

```
captureRequestBuilder.set(
    CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE,
    CameraMetadata.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON
)
```

So setting this parameter doesn't change anything.

Why video stabilization works in default system camera app but not in my own app using Camera2 API?

Comment: Could the problem come from the video mode? For example, Can you check if it works for 1080p 30fps? I think Image stabilization is limited on android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two types of stabilization that camera devices can support on Android

- **Video stabilization (Electronic Image Stabilization / EIS):** This is done as a post-processing step after image capture, by analyzing camera motion between frames and compensating for it by shifting the image a bit.  That's why there's a zoom-in effect, to give some room for that shift/warp. This stabilizes video over time, making consecutive image frames stable.  The controls for this are accessed via the [CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE) setting, as you've discovered.
- **Optical image stabilization (OIS):** This is a set of high-speed gyros and magnets around the camera lens, which rapidly shifts the lens (or sometimes the sensor) as the camera moves to stabilize the image. The amount of motion is limited, but it's very rapid, so it stabilizes images during a single exposure, not across multiple frames.  So it's generally only useful for snapshots, not video.  This is accessed via [SENSOR_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE).

Unfortunately, many Android manufacturers do not make their EIS implementations available to applications outside of their default camera app. That's because making a good EIS implementation is complicated, and the manufacturers want to limit it to only working with their own app's recording mode (which is a single target to fix). For example, EIS for recorded video often applies a 1-second delay so that it can adjust image transforms for future frames, in addition to past ones, which is hard to do for real-time apps. Some manufacturers make simpler algorithms visible, or otherwise manage to make EIS work for everyone, but for others, the device doesn't list support for EIS even when the built-in app uses it.

Turning on OIS probably works fine - you'd only see an effect on long-exposure images, where they'll be blurry due to handshake when OIS off, but be sharp when OIS is on.  Since it's a self-contained hardware unit, it's easy for manufacturers to make the on-switch available to everyone.

Comment: I was thinking that OIS is better for video than EIS. Ok, now it's more clear. So it should be EIS but Manufacture didn't make it available for Camera API, only for their camera app. Now I have to change logic if both stabilizations supported than by default EIS should be selected for my video recording app otherwise OIS if EIS isn't available. Thank you so much for a such detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

My experience with using this app (Droid Dash Cam) with the Galaxy S23 Ultra phone is that image stabilization is very effective using this app.  In the playback when I went over bumps I saw the mount shake but the image was rock solid.

Comment: Interesting. Because on Galaxy S22 Ultra video stabilization wasn't allowed yet for third party apps (from Google Play)